# Is the Code Review SE the right site for checking if the code of my Arduino project minimizes the risk of overheating as much as possible?

Tags: support, scope, broken-code

In a project of mine I use temperature sensors and an Arduino to dimm a light bulb to keep a box warm (in a certain temperature range above room temperature). I want others to look at my code if it has enough/the right safety measures so the box doesn't overheat which is what I want to prevent in case the temperature sensors or other parts of the hardware are faulty (or if my code itself has a bug I don't know of).

Of course I would provide the complete code and a rough overview over the hardware but I asked myself if the Code Review SE or the Arduino SE is the right site for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my eyes your question could only be off-topic for one rule.

> To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?
> -- [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

And from your description your code seems to work as intended. And your concerns seem to mostly be around "[correctness in unanticipated cases](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)".

Where if your question was "my light bulb keeps exploding" then your question would be off-topic.

Just note, questions on Code Review are a little different from other sites. You can ask questions, but answerer's are not bound by your questions. Whilst, in my experience, answerers try to be as helpful as possible by answering questions, we may not have the Arduino skills to properly answer the question. This is outlined in our help center:

> Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?
> -- [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

---

> I asked myself if the Code Review SE or the Arduino SE is the right site for this question.

In my eyes your question would be on-topic here.
But may not be answered the way you want.
However we can't comment on Arduino's rules as (AFAIK) we don't have any Arduino SE users here.

Comment: So if I understand correctly if my code works as intended my question is on-topic. You also said that I might get broader feedback than I asked for (which I don't mind) so does it even make sense to ask for specific feedback? Or is "Are the overheating countermeasures good enough?" just as good as "Please review my Arduino code?"?

Comment: You are correct. "does it even make sense to ask for specific feedback?" Yes, you can't get what you don't ask for.